# Best way to clone windows VM in GCP

Tags: google-compute-engine

Looking to see what's the best way to clone a domain joined VM with pre-installed software? I have a Windows 10 VM domain joined with software installed that I would like to clone. I have tried taking a snapshot and then deploying an instance based on that snapshot, but it creates a new VM with the snapshots VM name and SID. Thoughts or how is everyone else doing this?

Comment: I'm not skilled on windows.  Can you clarify the issue?  Is it that two such VMs can't co-exist on the same network?  What would a new cloned VM look like if it didn't have what you are finding now?  What is the underlying issue with what you have now? (Why doesn't it work for you).

Comment: So I'll use the VM I tried it on for example. I created a Windows 10 VM called "test", installed software, and joined to the domain. I took a snapshot of it in GCP, then created another windows 10 instance from that snapshot, when it powered on it had a new IP, but it was the same VM joined to the domain. So the new VM essentially had the new name in the domain as if the new instance was just renamed. Hopefully that makes more sense.

Comment: Worth noting for other people potentially encountering this, its actually risky to clone a windows VM from GCP, the two VMs identifying themselves with the same domain name / SID ended up causing Active Directory to trash the stored config for that machine, effectively losing the machine's config, and having to rebuild from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend building a Windows image for your instance, Windows snapshots can have duplication issues. see this documentation on how to create an Windows image [1]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/creating-windows-os-image

Comment: I will try this and see what results I get. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @AnthonyZepeda, I'm having the same issue on GCP (I even ended up accidentally nuking my existing server's AD config and having to rebuild it, ugh!). Did the Windows image route work for you? Something else?